# Empty message parse using ArduinoJSON from aedes MQTT server

Tags: esp32, mqtt

I'm using `aedes` as my custom MQTT broker and `PubSubClient` at the ESP32 side, together with the `ArduinoJSON` package.

My server test code:

```
import Aedes from "aedes";
import net from "net";

let port = process.env.MQTT_PORT || 1883; // MQTT Port

const id = "MY_SERVER";

const aedes = new Aedes({
    id: id,
});

aedes.on("client", async (client) => {
    console.log("Client conntected...");
});

aedes.on("subscribe", async (subscriptions, client) => {

    let topic = "cmd/" + client.id;

    let msg = {
        topic: topic,
        type: "test",
        param: "p1"
    };

    console.log("Sending command...")
    console.log(msg);

    this.aedes.publish(msg);

});

let server = net.createServer(aedes.handle, options);

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Find the server at: mqtt://localhost:${port}/`); 
});
```

When running I'm getting:

```
Client connected...
Sending command...
{ topic: 'cmd/4CA9A712B42A', type: 'test', param: 'p1' }
```

At the client (ESP32) side I have my PubSubClient callback as follows:

```
void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
    Serial.println("Message received.....");

    StaticJsonDocument<256> doc;
    deserializeJson(doc, payload, length);

    char *command = doc["type"];
    char *param = doc["param"];

    Serial.println(command);
    Serial.println(param);
}
```

The callback is being called property after subscription - but I'm not being able to parse the payload:

```
Message received.....
<empty line>
<empty line>
```

How can I fix the server or client to allow then to send/parse correctly the payload.

Comment: Could you `Serial.write(payload, length);` in the callback and show us what it prints?

Comment: Did it - payload has length zero, so nothing is coming from the server...

Comment: Do you have another way of testing the server? Maybe sniff the connection?

Comment: No way to sniff.... need to try different approach

Comment: Found the problem.... Needs to have a `payload` property when sending message:  `let msg = {topic: topic, payload: JSON.stringify({type: "test", param: "p1"})}` did the trick.